# Transform a propositional calculus formula so that $\varphi$ is a tautology iff $T(\varphi)$ is satisfiable.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is there an *efficient* way to translate $\varphi$ into $T(\varphi)$ such that the following holds:

$$ \text{$\varphi$ is a tautology} \;\; \textit{iff}  \;\; \text{$T(\varphi)$ is satisfiable} $$

By *efficient*, I mean one that *grows the size of the term* as little as possible while still being reasonably computationally efficient. I don't want to commit to an explicit bound like *linear in the number of symbols* or *polynomial in the number of symbols* in the question.

It is okay if the translation adds or removes propositional variables.

The motivation for this question is the fact that proofs of the satisfiability of a given proposition are very simple and lack internal structure; they can just consist of a list of the variables that are true, or equivalently, a list of the variables that are false.

I'm trying to understand more broadly if there are convenient ways of translating theories into propositional calculus in such a way that a witness of satisfiability corresponds to a proof of the original statement rather than corresponding to a counterexample, so to speak.

Certain transformations like [Tseytin's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation) are equisatisfiable, but I'm wondering about *exchanging the roles* of satisfiability and tautology, so to speak.

---

Suppose that my logical connectives are $\land, \lor, \lnot$ with their standard meanings and I have no symbols for truth values.

Further suppose that $P$ is my only propositional variable, so all wffs are built out of the finite alphabet $\{ \land, \lor, \lnot, P\}$ (and parentheses to force unique readings).

Here is one way to implement $T$. Let $\varphi[x:=v]$ denote a substitution that replaces $x$ with $v$.

We can define a naive $T$ as follows:

$$ T(\varphi) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=\!=} \varphi[P:=P \land \lnot P] \land \varphi[P:=P \lor \lnot P] $$

This amounts to a direct encoding of the brute force algorithm for checking the tautology of an expression; we check if $\varphi$ is true when $P$ holds and we check if $\varphi$ is true when $P$ is false.

We can define another translation $T'$ that results in very compact formulas, but basically just passes responsibility for solving the problem to a higher level.

$$ T'(\varphi) = P\land\lnot P \;\; \text{if $\varphi$ is not a tautology} $$
$$ T'(\varphi) = P \lor \lnot P \;\; \text{if $\varphi$ is a tautology} $$

Comment: I think your question is too open-ended. A polynomial-time solution would imply that NP = [Co-NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP) a positive solution to a significant open problem. Outside polynomial-time solutions, we need to know what you would accept "as reasonably computationally efficient".

Comment: I should have also asked `does this reduce to a known open problem`. I don't understand the subtleties for why the existence of such a procedure would imply that `NP = Co-NP`, or, indeed, exactly how certificates fit into the picture (since tautologies in classical propositional calculus can also have certificates like closed tableaux). From my perspective, an explanation of why this is the case would answer the question.

Comment: Satisfiability is an NP problem and tautology is a Co-NP problem. A polynomial-time reduction of either of these problems to the other would give NP = Co-NP.  Certificates for tautologies, e.g., proofs such as tableaux proofs, as far as we know, do not have sizes that are polynomial in the size of the tautology.

Comment: @RobArthan And crucially, satisfiability is NP-*complete*, and tautology is Co-NP-*complete*.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: sure. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @RobArthan You should make that an answer.